# Making a discord.js reaction help menu

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, im making a reation based help-menu for my discord bot. Here's my current code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'helpall',
    description: 'help embed menu',
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Moderation commands')
        .setDescription('Please enter . before every command to use it')
        .addFields(
            {name: '`.kick <@user>`', value: '`kicks a member from the server`'},
            {name: '`.ban <@user>`', value: '`bans a member from the server`'},
            {name: '`.prune <amount>`', value: '`deletes a certain amount of messages in the channel`'},
            {name: '`.lock`', value: '`locks the channel the message was sent in`'},
            {name: '`.unlock`', value: '`unlocks a previously locked channel`'},
            {name: '`.mute <@user>`', value: '`mutes a member`'},
            {name: '`.unmute <@user>`', value: '`unmutes a previously muted member`'}
        )
        .setColor('#FFC300')
        const sendembed1 = await message.channel.send(embed1)

        const nextemoji = '▶'
        const lastemoji = '◀'

        sendembed1.react(lastemoji)
        sendembed1.react(nextemoji)

        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return ['▶', '◀'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id
        }

        sendembed1.awaitReactions(filter, {max:1, time:60000, error: ["time"]}).then(
            async (collected) => {
                const reaction = collected.first()

                const embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Math commands')
                .setDescription('Please type . before every command to use it ')
                .addFields(
                    {name: '`.add <num1> <num2>`', value: '`adds 2 numbers and returns the sum`'},
                    {name: '`.sub <num1> <num2>`', value: '`subtracts 2 numbers and returns the difference`'},
                    {name: '`.multiply <num1> <num2>`', value: '`multiplies 2 numbers and returns the product`'},
                    {name: '`.divide <num1> <num2>`', value: '`divides 2 numbers and returns the quotient`'}
                )
                .setColor('#FFC300')

                if(reaction.emoji.name === '▶') {
                    sendembed1.edit(embed2)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This works and now all I want to do is make or add 2 more pages but I am not sure where to put the code to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're doing this is a bit hard. Try using an array or something.
Example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
let pages = [];
let page = 0;
//I'll do it normally.
//You can use array.append()
pages[0] = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Homepage")
pages[1] = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription("Another page")
//And many more
//...

message.channel.send(pages[0])
    .then(msg => {
        msg.react('⬅').then( r => {
        msg.react('➡')
        // Filters (I'll use arrow functions)
        const backwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => { reaction.emoji.name === '⬅' && user.id === message.author.id }
        const forwardsFilter = (reaction, user) => { reaction.emoji.name === '➡' && user.id === message.author.id }

        const backwards = msg.createReactionCollector(backwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})
        const forwards = msg.createReactionCollector(forwardsFilter, {timer: 6000})

        backwards.on('collect', (r, u) => {
            if(page === 0){ return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first()) } //The first aka Home page
            page --
            msg.edit(pages[page])
            return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
        });

        forwards.on('collect', (r, u) => { //r = reaction; u = user
            if(page === (pages.length - 1)){ return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())} //The last page
            page++
            embed.setDescription(pages[page-1])
            msg.edit(pages[page]);
            return r.users.remove(r.users.cache.filter(u => u === message.author).first())
        });
    });
});
```

Now put this thing in your `execute` function. You might change the embeds according to your needs

Comment: Thnx for helping me !